# Sorting in ATG 'RQLQueryForEach' droplet

Tags: repository, atg

I just want to know on what basis sorting is happening in the below 'RQLQueryForEach' droplet,

```
    <dsp:droplet name="RQLQueryForEach">
    <dsp:param name="OfferId" value="<%= offId %>"/>
    <dsp:param name="repository"   value="/com/tgt/coa/repository/COARepository"/>
    <dsp:param name="itemDescriptor" value="offer_catg_assoc"/>
    <dsp:param name="queryRQL" value="ofr_i=:OfferId"/>
    <dsp:setvalue param="offerItem" paramvalue="element"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="outputStart">
    <dsp:getvalueof id="repId" param="offerItem.repositoryId">
    <dsp:input type="checkbox" value="<%= repId %>" name="unAssocMe" checked="<%=false%>" />&nbsp;
    <dsp:getvalueof id="catgId" param="offerItem.prod_catg_seq_i">
```

Corresponding Item Descriptor:

```
<item-descriptor name="offer_catg_assoc" query-cache-size="1000" item-cache-size="10000" item-expire-timeout="3600000"
    query-expire-timeout="3600000" cache-mode="simple">
    <table name="COA_OFR_PROD_CATG" type="primary" id-column-names="OFR_PROD_C_SEQ_I">
        <attribute name="metaDataSchemaPattern" value="CMP_ADW"/>
        <attribute name="tablePrefix" value="CMP_ADW."/>
        <property name="ofr_prod_c_seq_i" data-type="int" sql-type="integer" column-name="OFR_PROD_C_SEQ_I" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="coa_run_seq_i" data-type="int" sql-type="integer" column-name="COA_RUN_SEQ_I" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="prod_catg_seq_i" data-type="int" sql-type="integer" column-name="PROD_CATG_SEQ_I" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="coa_asct_type_c" data-type="string" sql-type="char" column-name="COA_ASCT_TYPE_C" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="ofr_i" data-type="int" sql-type="bigint" column-name="OFR_I" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="crte_user_i" data-type="string" sql-type="char" column-name="CRTE_USER_I" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc"/>
        <property name="crte_d" data-type="date" sql-type="date" column-name="CRTE_D" required="true" group="offrcatgassoc">
        </property>
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

The above query is fetching datas from DB randomly.I'm unable to find how the records are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that default order is order by primary key in your case: "OFR_PROD_C_SEQ_I".
But RQLQueryForEach has property - "*sortProperties*" where you could specify your custom order.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sortProperties parameter with sorting properties. The following input parameter sorts your repository items **alphabetically** by **coa_asct_type_c**, then in **descending** order of **ofr_prod_c_seq_i**: e.g.

```
<dsp:param name="sortProperties" value="+coa_asct_type_c,ofr_prod_c_seq_i"/>
```

This page should give you more details on [RQLQueryForEach](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s1449rqlqueryforeach01.html)